# Server responded with 400 Bad Request during HTTP Post request

Tags: http-post, influxdb, at-command, sim800

I am using SIM800 to send HTTP Post request to a remote InfluxDB database. I have successfully sent HTTP Post request to the database from my computer using Curl as shown below.

```
01:~$ curl -i -XPOST 'http://<ip address>:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary 'location,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.99'
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: 3c958273-edb2-11eb-88ca-000000000000
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.6.3
X-Request-Id: 3c958273-edb2-11eb-88ca-000000000000
Date: Mon, 26 Jul 2021 01:38:54 GMT
```

After that when I tried using SIM800, I received 400 Bad Request after executing AT+HTTPACTION=1 . The remote server responded with "+HTTPACTION: 1,400,0" . Below are the AT Commands.

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","myAPN"
AT+SAPBR=1,1
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://<ip address>:8086/write?db=mydb"
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
AT+HTTPPARA="USERDATA","location,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.55"
AT+HTTPDATA=300,5000
AT+HTTPACTION=1
AT+HTTPREAD
AT+HTTPTERM 
AT+SAPBR=0,1
```

Besides that, i captured the packets when SIM800 sent http post request but could not find the http post body.

The http post body can be seen in the captured packets when sending http post using Curl.

I appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this matter. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work. Here are the AT commands:-

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","myAPN"
AT+SAPBR=1,1
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://<ip address>:8086/write?db=mydb"
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
AT+HTTPDATA=48,5000
location,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.55
AT+HTTPACTION=1
AT+HTTPREAD
AT+HTTPTERM 
AT+SAPBR=0,1
```

after executing the AT+HTTPDATA, quickly execute the HTTP data (location,host...).